# How do I command line interface to a redis server running on the same compute engine server as my nodejs app

Tags: node.js, redis, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

Summary: I cannot access redis-cli from my deployed nodejs app, I suspect because redis does not get packaged into the docker container that my code runs in.

Is there anyway to execute a command line targeted for my host server rather than executing within the docker?
Can I access redis-cli from within the docker container?

I have a nodejs app that I deploy to a Google compute engine instance.
The instance was created with bitnami debian nodejs which includes redis.

I use the following module to execute the redis cli
    const {exec} = require('child_process');

Redis is running and I can get and set keys from my code using the nodejs api.

However, to do a bulk insert of keys I need to execute the following command from a spawned process...
cat filname.txt | redis-cli --pipe
where filename has my keys in the correct format.

This all works when I run directly on the server. However, when I use google cloud deploy I lose access to the redis-cli. The specific error returns from the process is...
/bin/sh: 1: redis-cli: not found

I suspect this is because when I deploy, my code gets executed in a docker container. Being in the docker container I can still access redis via 127.0.0.1 but lose the ability to access it from the command line.

---

The full command and error message:

executing command:
    cat /tmp/test.txt | redis-cli --pipe

```
{ Error: Command failed: cat /tmp/test.txt | redis-cli --pipe
/bin/sh: 1: redis-cli: not found
  at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:294:12)
  at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:189:13)
  at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:970:16)
  at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:259:5)
killed: false,
code: 127,
signal: null,
cmd:
'cat /tmp/test.txt | redis-cli --pipe' }
```

Comment: maybe use a node redis library like https://github.com/NodeRedis/node_redis ?

Comment: Unfortunately the node redis libraries only implement the redis commands. The mass insertion is only available as a cli option.  https://redis.io/topics/mass-insert

Comment: how about the `client.batch([commands])`?
"This is recommended if you want to execute many commands at once but don't have to rely on transactions."
maybe can use in conjunction with async/parallelization libraries as well